# ADAL for Azure OAuth - redirect with POST

Tags: javascript, azure, http

I've been using the Azure Active Directory Authentication Library for java

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#web-application-to-web-api

I have the sample code working (Authenticating a user in my own WebApp using my company's AD Cloud instance)

There's one part I don't understand in the sequence:

1. The browser loads my application's landing page and user clicks "Sign in with Microsoft"
2. The browser makes a request to my server, which is redirected to the Microsoft Log In page (https://login.microsoftonline.com/MyTenantId/oauth2/authorize?client_id=...etc)
3. User logs into their Microsoft account
4. After processing the log on, the Microsoft server redirects the browser back to a secured uri on my server - *as a POST request*

How can they do a Redirect with POST?  I thought a WebServer (i.e. a Spring webapp) couldn't do this ?  Are they doing it client-side (i.e. Javascript?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is correct.

They return a small HTML page that includes a form, which is auto-submitted with JavaScript. If you disable JavaScript, you will see it.

Comment: sometimes it's crazy what you find out is "best practice" :)

Comment: They have to do it this way. They *could* POST it from their back-end, but that would have many disadvantages, one of them being that your cookies for your app would not be passed with the request.